# RANCID - timeout connecting PALOALTO in HA

Tags: backup, firewall, configuration, palo-alto-networks, rancid

When rancid try to connect via SSH to PALO (the active one) i get a time out message.
Connecting manually everything is ok.
I believe is something related to prompt containing parethesis.

```
add user fw-* backup-user 
add password fw-* {xxxxxx} {yyyyyyyy} 
add method fw-* {ssh} 
add autoenable fw-* 1
```

and this is the output from manual connection

```
backup-user@firewall-name(active)>
```

and this is the error i get

```
panlogin error: Error: TIMEOUT reached
```

Any clues? thanks